# What portable data backends are there which have fast append and random access?

Tags: c++, database, qt, storage

I'm working on a [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/) GUI for visualizing 'live' data which is received via a TCP/IP connection. The issue is that the data is arriving rather quickly (a few dozen MB per second) - it's coming in faster than I'm able to visualize it even though I don't do any fancy visualization - I just show the data in a [QTableView](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qtableview.html) object.

As if that's not enough, the GUI also allows pressing a 'Freeze' button which will suspend updating the GUI (but it will keep receiving data in the background). As soon as the Freeze option was disabled, the data which has been accumulated in the background should be visualized.

What I'm wondering is: since the data is coming in so quickly, I can't possibly hold all of it in the memory. The customer might even keep the GUI running over night, so gigabytes of data will accumulate. What's a good data storage system for writing this data to disk? It should have the following properties:

- It shouldn't be too much work to use it on a desktop system
- It should be fast at appending new data at the end. I never need to touch previously written data anymore, so writing into anywhere but the end is not needed.
- It should be possible to randomly access records in the data. This is because scrolling around in my GUI will make it necessary to quickly display the N to N+20 (or whatever the height of my table is) entries in the data stream.

The data which is coming in can be separated into records, but unfortunately the records don't have a fixed size. I'd rather not impose a maximum size on them (at least not if it's possible to get good performance without doing so).

Maybe some SQL database, or something like [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/)? It would be great if somebody could share his experience with such scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/) might do the trick. It seems to be fast. Unfortunately, I have no data flow like yours, but it works well as a backend for a log recorder. I have a GUI where you can view the n, n+k logs.

You can also try [SOCI](http://soci.sourceforge.net/) as a C++ database access API, it seems to work fine with sqlite (I have not used it for now but plan to).

my2c

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of `sqlite`. I used it before, it might be an option.

Comment: @Frerich: You are welcome. I'm interested in the performance of the tool you will use. If the perfs are really bad, you will end with files ...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a simple file based solution.

**If you can use fixed size records:** If the you get the data continuously with constant sample rate, random access to data is easy and very fast when you know the time stamp of first data point and the sample rate. If the sample rate varies, then write time stamp with each data point. Now random access requires binary search, but it is still fast enough.

**If you have variable size records:** Write the variable size data to one file and to other file write indexes (which are fixed size) to the data file. And if the sample rate varies, write time stamps too. Now you can do the random access fast using the index file.

If you are using Qt to implement this kind of solution, you need two sets of QFile and QDataStream instances, one for writing and one for reading.

And a note about performance: don't flush the file after every data point write. But remember to flush the file before doing any random access to it.